# Changes to Vue data property do not update in template using async/await and v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a 'errors' property in my data function and it will be populated with errors (key/value pairs) once a error is thrown and caught by a async/await try/catch.  It successfully populates my errors property with the error messages for their respective fields, but it does not reflect that in the template where I'm using v-if/v-for to output the data. Any advice?

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input type="text" v-model="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <div v-for="(error, index) in errors.email" :key="index">{{ error }}</div>
    <br />
    <input type="text" v-model="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <div v-if="errors.username">
      <div v-for="(error, index) in errors.username" :key="index">{{ error }}</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="text" v-model="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <div v-if="errors.password">
      <div v-for="(error, index) in errors.password" :key="index">{{ error }}</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="text" v-model="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <div v-if="errors.confirmPassword">
      <div v-for="(error, index) in errors.confirmPassword" :key="index">{{ error }}</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <vue-recaptcha
      ref="recaptcha"
      @verify="onVerify"
      @expired="onExpired"
      :sitekey="recaptchaSitekey"
      :loadRecaptchaScript="true"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import VueRecaptcha from "vue-recaptcha";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: null,
      username: null,
      password: null,
      confirmPassword: null,
      recaptchaSitekey: process.env.VUE_APP_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,
      recaptchaResponse: null,
      errors: {}
    };
  },
  components: {
    VueRecaptcha
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      const formData = {
        email: this.email,
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword,
        recaptcha: this.recaptchaResponse
      };
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch("signUp", formData);
      } catch (err) {
        err.forEach(e => {
          this.errors[e.field] = this.errors[e.field] || [];
          this.errors[e.field].push(e.message);
        });
      }
      console.log(this.errors);
    },
    onVerify(response) {
      this.recaptchaResponse = response;
    },
    onExpired() {
      console.log("Expired");
    },
    resetRecaptcha() {
      this.$refs.recaptcha.reset();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: You're adding new properties to `errors`. Standard reactivity caveat: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats. Either use `$set` or create a new `errors` object each time or pre-populate the initial `errors` object with the appropriate properties.

Comment: @skirtle ahh! I see! Thanks for the link!